# How to disable button touch at the start in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this button:

```
@IBAction func touch(sender: AnyObject) {
println("Hello, world!")
}
```

and another:

```
@IBAction func toggle(sender: AnyObject) {
//code to enable touch of button "touch"
```

I want to disable user touch of "touch" at the start of the app, and enable touch after tapping "toggle", how to realize it by code and in storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update with swift 2 and IOS 10 is `self.touch.isEnabled = false`.

They have gotten rid of `enabled` and replaced it with `isEnabled`.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 syntax**

```
button.isEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `@IBOutlets` to access the buttons at runtime. In InterfaceBuilder ctrl-drag the button to the top of your custom class file, choose *Outlet* and give it a descriptive name. It will look like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var touch: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var toggle: UIButton!

    // Disable in `viewDidLoad`:
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.touch.enabled = false
    }

    @IBAction func toggle(sender: AnyObject) {
        //code to enable touch of button "touch"
        self.touch.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button in the storyboard - uncheck the `enabled` checkbox. 
To enable it in code you should create an outlet and then set the `enabled` property to `true`:

```
button.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

```
myButton.isEnabled = false;
```

Solution 2   //Desperate way to disable button by disabling the user interaction.

```
myButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
```